# Ratio of difference and sum of i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I just noticed that for two i.i.d. exponential random variables $X$ and $Y$, the combination $\frac{X-Y}{X+Y}$ appears to be distributed uniformly on $[-1, 1]$ (ignoring the case $X=0, Y=0$ for the moment):

```
x <- rexp(1000000)
y <- rexp(1000000)
hist((x-y)/(x+y))
```

[image: Histogram]

Is this a known fact? I was unable to find a reference to this, and would appreciate one if it does exist. Furthermore, I'd be interested if there are any known results about the dependent case.

Comment: I’m sure it is known, note that it is equal to $1 - 2Y/(X+Y)$ and that $Y/(X+Y)$ is known to be Uniform on (0,1) from the generic relationship between and Gamma and Beta distributions.

Comment: Perfect justification from @guy. Note that the case $X=Y=0$ is irrelevant, being of measure zero.

Comment: Yes, good catch, @guy! I would accept this as the answer if you could post it as such (to increase your rep score ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $X, Y$ are iid $\mathcal{E}(1)$, as the scale parametyer is irrelevant for the distribution of the ratio. Using theshale-scale parametrization of the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), then, this is the same as the gamma distribution $\mathcal{Gamma}(1,1)$. The sum $X+y$ is then $\mathcal{Gamma}(2,1)$ and the ratio $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is $\mathcal{Beta}(1,1)$, that is, uniform.

Noting that
$$ \frac{X-Y}{X+Y}=\frac{X+Y-2Y}{X+Y}=1-2\frac{Y}{X+Y}$$
so is 1-twice a random variable having the standard uniform distribution. So is uniform on $(-1,1)$.

(all standard results used contained in above wiki link).